# Make hovered tooltip disappear when clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I am trying to create a tooltip for whatever that needs it on my website, e.g. a button, text, etc. So far I have something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/f06q3cLg/

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}

.content .parent {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.content .parent:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  animation: 0.1s fadeInTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.content .parent:hover:before {
  animation: 0.1s fadeInTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.content .parent:active .tooltip-wrapper {
  animation: 0.05s fadeOutTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.content .parent:active:before {
  animation: 0.05s fadeOutTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.content .parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper.bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 8px);
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper .tooltip {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Keyframes */

@keyframes fadeInTooltip {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutTooltip {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="parent">
    Hover me
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <span class="tooltip">This is my tooltip</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As such, it works somewhat fine. My issue is that I would like the tooltip to disappear when I click the button. Now it vanishes, and then comes back with a `0.4s` delay as the hover effect actually has. Ideally the tooltip should disappear as long as my mouse is still on the button, but when I remove it and re-enters the button, then the tooltip should re-appear.

I'm not sure if this is even achievable with pure CSS, but any JS would also do.

Comment: As an aside-- I would recommend avoiding using `<div>`s as stand-ins for `<button>` elements-- unless done properly, it represents an accessibility antipattern as it cannot be properly interacted with by keyboards and other assistive devices, nor can it be read with full context by screen readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `:active` is only applied as long as the mouse is down.

[mdn: `:active`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active):

> The `:active` CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being activated by the user. When using a mouse, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

What you could do (if you want to stay CSS only) is to use `tabindex="0"` on the `<div class="parent">` and `:focus` instead of `:active`. But you need to verify that using  `tabindex="0"` here won't hurt usability.

> Ideally the tooltip should disappear as long as my mouse is still on the button, but when I remove it and re-enters the button, then the tooltip should re-appear.

That won't work with `:focus` either. I'm pretty sure that this behavior can only be achieved with JS. If it is possible with CSS only it likely would be a pretty hacky solution.

But from the perspective of a user, this seems to be counterintuitive that the tooltip won't appear after clicked.

A JavaScript solution that does what you want could look like this.
It is a simplified version of the tooltip to only show the relevant parts.
Every element having a tooltip has an attribute `data-has-tooltip`.

```js
// event delegation for all mouse down event:
// this ensures that the code also works for elements that have been added to the DOM after that script was executed.
document.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {
  // check if the mousedown happened in an element with a tooltip
  const element = evt.target.closest('[data-has-tooltip]');
  if (element) {
    // if the user already clicked on the element ignore the click
    if (!element.classList.contains('active')) {
      // add the active class to the element so that hover won't show the toolip
      element.classList.add('active');

      function removeActiveOnLeave() {
        // remove the active class
        element.classList.remove('active');

        // remove the mouseleave event listener again
        element.removeEventListener('mouseleave', removeActiveOnLeave)
      }

      // add an event listener for mouseleave to remove the active class
      element.addEventListener('mouseleave', removeActiveOnLeave)
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.parent {
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid red;
   padding: 0.5rem;
   margin: 0.5rem;
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.parent:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.parent.active:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="parent" data-has-tooltip>
    Hover me A
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <span class="tooltip">This is my tooltip A </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="parent" data-has-tooltip>
    Hover me B
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <span class="tooltip">This is my tooltip B</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is just excellent.

Comment: And just in case anyone needs it (I did), the Angular way of doing your JS is just to change `document.addEventListener('mousedown', (evt) => {` with `@HostListener('document:mousedown', ['$event'])
    onMouseDown(evt) {`

Comment: @DenverDang yes sure if you use a framework like angular, vue, react, svelte, … you need to adapt the event listeners. And you also need to change the logic a bit to match the way how those frameworks work. Event delegation  and the pure JavaScript event listeners is something won’t use in that case and instead use the event handling matching those libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating 'display' property.

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
const toolTip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');

parent.addEventListener('click', () => {
if(toolTip.style.display !== 'none') {
    toolTip.style.display = 'none';
}else {
  toolTip.style.display = 'grid';
}
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using jQuery 3.4.1:

```js
$(".parent").click(function () {
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").css("display", "none");
});
```

The only downfall with that solution is once you click and re-hover in the same session, the SCSS `:hover` doesn't work properly.

No need to stress, just add the following if you want that functionality:

```js
$(".parent").hover(function () {
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").css("display", "block");
});
```

Try it out in the attached snippet:

```js
$(".parent").click(function () {
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").css("display", "none");
});

$(".parent").hover(function () {
    $(".tooltip-wrapper").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  place-content: center;
}

.content .parent {
  border: 1px red solid;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.content .parent:hover .tooltip-wrapper {
  animation: 0.1s fadeInTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.content .parent:hover:before {
  animation: 0.1s fadeInTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

.content .parent:active .tooltip-wrapper {
  animation: 0.05s fadeOutTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.content .parent:active:before {
  animation: 0.05s fadeOutTooltip;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.content .parent:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper.bottom {
  top: calc(100% + 8px);
}

.content .parent .tooltip-wrapper .tooltip {
  max-width: 300px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 11px;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  line-height: 1.3;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Keyframes */

@keyframes fadeInTooltip {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutTooltip {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="parent">
    Hover me
    <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
      <span class="tooltip">This is my tooltip</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR, you can see it working in this [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/sj7xh0my/19/)  with your initial
SCSS.

You can uncomment the second function to see the hover working again after clicking.

Comment: Why did you add `jquery` as tag to the question? Sure the OP says `but any JS would also do.` but then you could also add any other javascript library that comes to your mind.

Comment: @t.niese Personal preference. Not required for it to parse properly. I changed them back to classes if that is sufficient for you.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. If jQuery wasn't tagged it wasn't desired (and it's ever more commonly not desired in 2022).

Comment: I know the pros and cons of id and class and where ids and classes have to be or should not be used and whether it is relevant for the question or not, so it doesn't really matter to me. But you can't assume that any reader of that question has the same knowledge and those might not know if that change was needed or not. And changing a class to an id makes the script really limited because with that it could only be used for one element with one tooltip and you would need to create distinct ids for every element that should have a tooltip.

Comment: @t.niese Well, it's a good thing it is compatible with both classes and ids. I can see how it could cause confusion for some thinking it may be limited to only `ID`'s. I should have specified. Appreciate the comment.

Comment: I grabbed it from the fiddle in the question using the browser inspector.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="content">
   <div class="parent" onClick="myFunction()">
      Hover me
      <div class="tooltip-wrapper">
       <span class="tooltip" id="tooltip">This is mytooltip</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function myFunction(){
  var tooltip=document.getElementById("tooltip");
  if (tooltip.style.display=="none") {        
 document.getElementById("tooltip").style.display="block";
  } else {
  document.getElementById("tooltip").style.display="none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).